# WP Maximum post number retrieved AND maximum post per page

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a way to specify a maximum number of post to retrieve AND also specify a maximum of post per page (`post_per_page`). (eg: 1 post per page and retrieve 80 posts to get a maximum of 80 pages...)

There used to be a way to do it but it has been apparently deprecated which was `numberposts` but I can't found an alternative. Any ideas welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems WP doesn't let you set a maximum for amount of posts to retrieve but I'm not sure why you need that, If you want to limit you pagination to 80 you can just do it manually.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$my_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $paged
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $my_query_args );


// Your Output.


next_posts_link( 'Next Posts', 80 );
previous_posts_link( 'Previous Posts' ); 

// Make sure to clean up after output.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also you have access to both `$my_query->found_posts` and `$my_query->max_num_pages` which you can use to limit your custom pagination function.

If you're not using custom pagination function you can consider using the new WP Pagination function called [get_the_posts_pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_pagination/).

Comment: Perfect Michael, thanks for the tips, didn't know you could restrict the pagination!